# Unique combination of composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to create table with composite key, combinations of which must be unique.

For example,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST3](
    [field1][int] NOT NULL,
    [field2][int] NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (field1,field2)
)
GO
```

rows:

```
field1    field2
----------------
   1        2
   2        1
```

How to prevent such behavior? I need to have an error when user inserts row (`2,1`) to the table which already has row (`1,2`)

Comment: Easiest way is to add a check constraint ensuring they are always entered in a consistent order. e.g. `CHECK (field1 < field2)` then your existing PK ensures this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to do that using a user-defined type, but IMHO this sounds like a bad design and possibly an XY problem.

If you are trying to create a many-to-many table (e.g. a table for mutual friends) I would recommend instead using a check constraint to always make sure `field1` is strictly less than `field2`.

You can even take it a step further and require the use of a stored procedure to insert rows, or create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger. This would put the row in the right order for you, this way you don't have to rely on the front end knowing which order the columns should be in.

Comment: Additionally, why not use a stored procedure to insert the data? Take two parameters, do the logic inside the stored procedure to put the lesser of the two first, check for duplicates, etc.

Comment: @KyleHale Heh just edited my answer to include that. You beat me to it by about 10 seconds :)

Comment: I should say, that type of my fields is (uniqueidentifier). Can i compare fields of this type?

Comment: I also was thinking about trigger, which will check the uniqueness. But i was wondering whether exists any option for this while creating the table with composite key

Comment: @user1561325 Sure you can compare `uniqueidentifier`s. Run [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10182) a few times to see.

Answer (score 1):

Some insert ( and update ) trigger would be possible solution, i.e.

```
create trigger prevent 
on TEST3 
for insert 
as 
if (select count(1) 
    from TEST3, inserted 
    where TEST3.field1=inserted.field2 and TEST3.field2=inserted.field1) > 0  
/* Cancel the insert and print a message.*/
  begin
    rollback transaction 
    print "Failed." 
  end  
/* Otherwise, allow it. */
else
  print "Added!"
```

Comment: FYI it's a corner case, but I believe this trigger would still allow me to do `INSERT INTO TEST3 VALUES (1,2),(2,1)`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what 'corner case' means here. Plese explain. Also I am not able to test your case because in ASE I am using, such multiple insert is not allowed. But I am quite sure that this trigger should work fine in other RDBMS.

Comment: A corner case is a very unlikely situation that may produce unexpected results. In this case it is highly unlikely someone will do a multiple insert with the same two ids backwards. However, it is possible and when done it will produce the unexpected result of letting the query through.